# Making Bootstrap inputs align vertically on mobile but horizontally on desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="first-name" name="first_name" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="sr-only" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="last-name" name="last_name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This ends up looking like this on mobile:
[image]

I tried adding `col-md-offset-4` to the divs with the inputs.

I tried adding `justify-content-center` to the divs.

When on desktop, I need them to align like this so I have the class `form-inline` added by JS on larger resolutions:
[image]

How do I get these to align so they are centered with the submit button but still keep the expected alignment on desktop?

Comment: You need all the 3 elements to be in horizontal only the input text fileds?

Comment: You can remove div.col-md-2 and assign text-align:center to the button itself. It is inline element so it'll respect that.

Comment: Also your button is within a row, you have to remove it from the row as well

Comment: I need it to flow back up to be to the right of the input field when not on mobile, which is why I have it in a separate column.

Comment: your question is too confusing, what you want and what you got? please explain what you need in which resolution?

Comment: I have the inputs aligned on desktop so they are stacked the but submit button is to the right of the bottom input as shown in the second image. However, when someone views them on mobile, I want everything including the submit button to align vertically as shown in the first image.

Comment: @eComEvo If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your code like below

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
            <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="first-name" name="first_name" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="sr-only" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="last-name" name="last_name" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                Submit
            </button>
            </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

see below output in full expand view, if you want this to work for small screen as well then you have to class `col-sm-4` for ex.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  
  <form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
            <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="first-name" name="first_name" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="sr-only" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="last-name" name="last_name" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                Submit
            </button>
            </div>
    </div>

</form>
  
  
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See my updated question. I left some details out that I should have put in there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question correctly but I tried to solve it.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form>
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
      <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="first-name" name="first_name" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
      <label class="sr-only" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="last-name" name="last_name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 text-center text-md-left mt-3 mt-md-0">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```